# how to set ListPopupWindow below its anchor view?

Tags: android

here is my code

`MainActivity.java`

in onCreate()

```
productName = (EditText) findViewById(
    R.id.product_name);
listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(
        MainActivity.this);
listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
        MainActivity.this,
    R.layout.list_item, products));


listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(productName);
listPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
listPopupWindow.setHeight(400);

listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
listPopupWindow.setPromptPosition(ListPopupWindow.POSITION_PROMPT_BELOW);
listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(
        MainActivity.this);
productName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listPopupWindow.show();
    }
});
```

how can i set `ListPopupWindow` below my anchorview(EditText) ?

Comment: have you tried `setVerticalOffset (int offset)`

Comment: now i have another problem like, i can not click parent view item when ListpopupWindow is open. plz help me.

Comment: & why should that suprise you? its `modal` use this [ListPopupWindow.setModal (true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html#setModal%28boolean%29) , try (if) it will work, with that when the parent is touched, the it will be dismissed

Answer (score 2):

by customizing height and width, solved my problem. its depend on screen resolution and your coded height and width and its anchor view positioning in a screen.

```
listPopupWindow.setWidth(250);
listPopupWindow.setHeight(300);
```

this change solved the problem.

Comment: why don't you use wrap content then?